# What does "download or create" mean in a tofrodos context?

Tags: shell, ssh

I keep [seeing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148575/how-to-install-zpanel) this phrase "download or create" in tutorials right after `tofrodos`. What would be an example of how to download or create? I just get stuck in

```
^
^
^
```

mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> apt-get -y install tofrodos
> ```
>
> **Download or create** ZPX_ubuntu_12-04_auto_installer.sh

The author means you need to transfer the "ZPX_ubuntu_12-04_auto_installer.sh" shell script to the server, and if necessary, change to the directory you saved the script in using the `cd` command, before entering the commands below:

> ```
> fromdos ZPX_ubuntu_12-04_auto_installer.sh
> chmod +x ZPX_ubuntu_12-04_auto_installer.sh
> ./ZPX_ubuntu_12-04_auto_installer.sh
> ```

He seems to be referring to a particular script included in a .zip file [posted on a web forum](http://forums.zpanelcp.com/showthread.php?7277-ZPX-Auto-Installer-for-Ubuntu-12-04).

You may be able to download the .zip file to your computer, extract it, and then use the `sftp` or `scp` program to transfer just the shell script to the server. Alternatively, you could use `wget` or `curl` to download the .zip file to the server and then the `unzip` command to unzip it.

A graphical SFTP client like [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) may help for the former approach. The Firefox add-on [cliget](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cliget/) may help for the latter, especially because the file is hosted on a password-protected web forum.

`fromdos` is just a utility program to convert a text file from DOS/Windows format to Unix format by stripping out all the carriage return characters. Perhaps using this command is necessary because the author of the script used a Windows text editor or an ASCII-mode FTP transfer before zipping up the file. Of course, you need the file on the server if you are trying to run the command on the server.

Comment: so if i have ZPX_ubuntu_12-04_auto_installer.sh, and i'm currently in the folder where it is located, and i go through the commands, then I can skip the "download or create" part? or does something *have* to happen after that first `tofrodos` command?

Comment: @brentonstrine: Yes, you have already "created" the file on the server if the folder it is in is on the server, not just on your desktop or laptop PC. You still need to run the `fromdos` command to remove the carriage returns and the `chmod +x` command to set the execute bit.